# Is there a reason Workbook_BeforeSave Cancel = True would not be working for me?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a reason the below code would not be working for me? I got this code directly from the Microsoft website and it is not working. The file saves whether I select Yes or No. I do need to tweak it a little bit but want to get this working before I start messing with it.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel as Boolean)

a = MsgBox("Do you really want to save the workbook?", vbYesNo) 
If a = vbNo Then Cancel = True 

End Sub
```

Comment: It should work. If you put a breakpoint into the code, does it execute when you try to save? Do you have other code (in an addon or something) capturing the save event? Is the document on the cloud? (excel file on sharepoint seems to be saved even if cancel is true?)

Comment: I do have a separate SaveAs macro but it is in its own module and runs off of a form control button so I wouldn't think it would affect this. I put a breakpoint on the If a = line and it did execute, highlighted If a = vbNo Then in yellow and highlighted Cancel = True in red. I selected No by the way if that helps

Comment: If at the end of the sub Cancel is True then your workbook won't be saved. Note that the Excel's UI will say that the workbook is saved, but is won't be the case. (check the last modified date on the filesystem)

Comment: You can check the value of the Success parameter in the Workbook_AfterSave event, if true the file has been saved, if false it hasn't.

Comment: I checked whether the If statement and message box is working correctly and it is and it is still saving. I don't know what is going on. I'm not sure how to check the value of the Success parameter but I threw a macro in there to put No in a cell if I selected No on the message box and it did proving the message box and if statement is working correctly but I confirmed that it is still saving regardless

Comment: just put `Debug.Print "Saved", Success` in the AfterSave event, the result will show in the immediate window

Comment: Well, I did just that and it says Saved True whether I click Yes or No

Comment: I think I read somewhere online and you mentioned Add-ins earlier, the following are the active Add-ins I have, could they be causing issues? Acrobat PDFMaker Office COM Addin, Microsoft Power Map for Excel, Microsoft Power Pivot for Excel, OneStreamExcelAddIn and OneStreamExcelAddIn.XFFunctions

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you test

```
IF MsgBox("Do you really want to save the workbook?", vbYesNo) = vbNo then Cancel=True
```

Comment: Well, I tried it on one of my coworkers computers and it worked fine so it must just be my computer?

Comment: If it's only your computer and you said something about Add-Ins just switch off Add-Ins one by one and then every time test again. Perhaps there is another code which reacts to the events.